# I found a weird occurrence with equal angle polygons and sine waves and i need help proving it

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, polygons, angle, trigonometric-series

[Here is a desmos graph that visualizes what I am about to say](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vrnij7nsq5)

- Okay, let's say we have a polygon with $s$ sides and $a = \frac{360°}{s}$.
- All of those polygon's angles are equal and all of it's sides are also equal.
- The polygon is formed using the sine and cosine methods (look at the desmos graph for refrence).

My hypothesis is that if a $\sin(x \times a)$ wave is run through the shape and $s$ is any even number, or $5$ or $7$ then the sine will cut the the polygon into two exact halves (which all the times I observed the halves will not be cut at the polygon's points)

*TL;DR*

What I need help with is proving that if you run a $\sin(x \times a)$ wave through a polygon with $s$ sides, and $a = \frac{360°}{s}$, and $s = \text{even}$ or $s = 5$ or $s = 7$ then the wave will cut the polygon exactly in half. Ergo all the postive $s$ values that won't cut it in half are $3, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, ...$

Can someone help me prove this? Seems like a fun question to tackle.

Side note:

If you want to complicate it even more let's have not only $y = \sin(x \times a)$ but also $x = \sin(y \times a)$, [have fun!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/koyiye6zop)

Comment: If $s$ is even then the symmetry of the polygon and $\sin$ about the $y$-axis should do it.

Comment: "The polygon is formed using the sine and cosine methods" - please explain. Also, I believe you mean $a = \frac{360^{\circ}}{s}$.

Comment: @WillFisher: does it not also depend on the orientation? If you rotate the square so that its sides are not parallel to the axes or at $45^{\circ}$ to them, I'm not sure that it works.

Comment: @NickD fixed...

Comment: You fixed one but not the other - but I'm still waiting for an explanation of the quoted sentence.

Comment: Quibble: *"All of those polygon's angles are equal (and thus all of it's [sic] sides are equal)."* This seems to be saying that the sides are equal *because* the angles are equal; this is not a true assertion (unless the polygon is a triangle). Just say instead: *"All of the polygon's angles are equal, and all of its sides are equal."*

Comment: is this just roots of unity? I'm not sure what the desmos graph is showing

Comment: @NickD What i meant was that i drew the points in a certain orientation using sin and cosine around the unit circle... look at this picture: https://ibb.co/iupX0T

Comment: @qwr : It's $\mathrm{i}\zeta_n$ for $\zeta_n$ a primitive $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity.  (That is, the point $(0,1)$ is always a vertex.)  (Alternatively, he swapped all the coordinates of the roots of unity.)

Comment: The property fails for $5$-gons and $7$-gons (and odd-gons in general). You can see this by drawing a line through the "closest" vertex and the center. (The line will pass through the midpoint of the opposite side.) The sine-wave diverges from that line in identical (but inverted) ways on either side of the $y$-axis, but that vertex is further from the center then that midpoint. Therefore, the two triangular-ish regions determined by the line, the sine-wave, and the polygon have different areas, so that the sine-wave does not bisect the polygon's area.

Comment: @Blue You got confused... ALL of the odds fail except 5 and 7

Comment: @AmitTPB Read the comment more carefully. There is no "except." The odds  _all_ fail, _including_ $5$ and $7,$ and the comment explains how to see that this is true.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is an area symmetric about the $y$-axis and $x$-axis, and $f$ is an odd function. We then have that
$$\begin{aligned}
|(x,y)\in A : y >f(x)| &= |(-x,-y)\in A : y <f(x)| \\
&= |(x,-y)\in A : y <f(x)|  \\
&= |(x,y)\in A : y <f(x)|
\end{aligned}$$
where the first line comes from the fact that $f$ is odd, the second line comes from the fact that $(-x,-y)\in A$ if and only if $(x,-y)\in A$ (symmetric about $y$-axis), and the third line comes from $(x,-y)\in A$ if and only if $(x,y)\in A$ (symmetric about $x$-axis). Clearly if $s$ is even then the polygon is symmetric about both the axes and moreover $\sin(ax)$ is also odd for any $a$. Proving the cases for the odd numbers you mentioned could be done tediously with some calculus.

Comment: can you show me how to figure out the special cases of 5 and 7?